# Using WordPress Importer, how to import media only?

Tags: import

I'm using WordPress Importer, and I can't figure out how to import media only? It ends up importing menu's and everything and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the WP Importer Plugin to export only attachments.

There's a pastebin with a custom Importer Plugin ready to be used: http://pastebin.com/RVBQ7icG

Via https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-advanced-export-for-wp-wpmu-how-to-export-attachments-only?replies=2#post-2734076

Answer (score 0):

Go to WordPress dashboard > tools > export > media > select date range.
Default exporter and importer.